# SpyOn calling actual implementation of method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit-test test cases for an angular application and I am using `SpyOn()` method to spy on a service method.

I am testing a service that has a method called `getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime()` which internally calls another service method called
`utilService.getHour()` and `utilService.getWeekday()`

I have used spies on these 2 methods and returned number `2` and `5` respectively after which the `getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime()` must return `7`.

Now when I call the service method `getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime()` the return value from spy is not used, instead the actual function itself is being called causing test to fail.

BoardSharedService.spec.ts

```
describe('BoardSharedService', () => {
  let service: BoardSharedService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        BoardSharedService,
        UtilService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should fetch data', () => {
    service = TestBed.get(BoardSharedService);
    const getHourSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UtilService', ['getHour']);
    const getWeekDaySpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UtilService', ['getWeekDay']);

    getHourSpy.getHour.and.returnValue(2);
    getWeekDaySpy.getWeekDay.and.returnValue(5);

    expect(service.getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime()).toBe(7);
    expect(service.getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

and boardSharedService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BoardSharedService {

  constructor(private utilService: UtilService) { }

  getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime() {
    const currentHour = this.utilService.getHour();
    const currentDay = this.utilService.getWeekDay();
    if (currentHour < 6 || currentHour > 17) {
      // PM
      if (currentDay === Day.Friday) {
        return 7; // Friday PM
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

and I get the following error

```
BoardSharedService should fetch data
Expected 1 to be 7.
Error: Expected 1 to be 7.
```

Need help.!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `jasmine` `spyObj` in the providers for `UtilService`.

Then you can `.and.returnValue(some_value)` on the methods of the `UtilService`.

```
providers: [
        BoardSharedService,
        {provide : UtilService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('UtilService', ['getHour', 'getWeekDay']);
      ]
```

In the spec you can do something like this

```
  it('should fetch data', () => {
    // UPDATE: You are doinf expect(service.getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // And you have not spy'd on service.getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime method, it will throw error.
    jasmine.spyOn(service, 'getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime').and.callThrough();
    service = TestBed.get(BoardSharedService);

    let utilService= TestBed.get(UtilService);

    utilService.getHour.and.returnValue(2);
    utilService.getWeekDay.and.returnValue(5);

    expect(service.getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime()).toBe(7);
    expect(service.getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: It worked somewhat but, now I get 

Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()

Comment: @KedarUdupa, I have updated the answer, you need to do `jasmine.spyOn(service, 'getCurrentBoardTimeIdByCurrentTime').and.callThrough();` as you are expecting the method to have been called.

Comment: That Worked..Thank you. @Basavaraj Bhusani